# Regex white list for input validation - accent insensitive

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, validation

I'd like to be able to constrain user input to a white list of valid characters, but I don't want to prevent people from other cultures from signing up.
So far, I have this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9èéêëàáâãäçìíîïòóôõöùúûü-_]*$
```

It allows for most French accents, but the list of accents in the latin character set are IMMENSE!  I would prefer to use a white list instead of a black list, in case I miss something.

*Note*, This will be for C# but I'd like to use the regex for client side validation to be consistent on both sides. I'm HTML encoding the input when I save it to the database as well.

Is there a more elegant way of making the regex accent insensitive, but still being restrictive enough to prevent XSS?  I don't want to alienate my users.

I would like to be able to have some punctuation but not open myself up for XSS attacks, for example, I want someone to enter their company name: If someone worked at Yahoo!, they should be able to sign up.

Comment: The ECMAscript RegExp class does not support unicode, beyond the \u.... escape to match a single code point: [ECMA-262 Standard][1]. For example, the `\w` escape only includes the ASCII letters and digits, plus "_".


  [1]: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Comment: Am I going about this the wrong way?  I guess the broader question is what's the best validation on the server side to prevent XSS (other than simply HTML encoding everything)?

Comment: I'm going to split up the server side functions as having one for only alphanumeric and one with punctuation.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\w+$
```

Couldn't you just use the alphanumeric flag, I believe that accepts the accents.

Comment: I'm getting this error in runtime:
parsing "^\w+*$" - Nested quantifier *

Comment: @Dave, I'm sure he meant either `^\w+$` or `^\w*$`. This is just a misspelling.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a regex noob :S

Comment: I'm liking the \w, but how do I selectively add some punctuation to it?

Comment: @Dave, just write the punctuation after it.  Say you want a word then a period:

Comment: @Ollie, /\w+./ doesn't match Yahoo! or Yahooé.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use unicode range like [\u00C0-\u017E] propably covers all bases for accent (but you should check character map to make sure, as i don't know what accents italian language has).

Comment: You can look here for what it accepts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#C1_Controls_and_Latin-1_Supplement  and maybe change for your own needs. My example is only covering accented letters. You will still need to do A-z0-9

Answer (score 2):

fwiw: I use a home brew function that returns a RegExp for all diacrits:

```
function diacritsRegEx(global, caseinsitive, multiline){
        var modifiers =   (global       ? 'g' : '') 
                        + (multiline    ? 'm' : '')
                        + (caseinsitive ? 'i' : ''); 
        return new RegExp(
             ['[\\.\\-a-z\\s]|',            // [a-z, . - and space]
              '[\\300-\\306\\340-\\346]|',  // all accented A, a
              '[\\310-\\313\\350-\\353]|',  // all accented E, e
              '[\\314-\\317\\354-\\357]|',  // all accented I, i
              '[\\322-\\330\\362-\\370]|',  // all accented O, o
              '[\\331-\\334\\371-\\374]|',  // all accented U, u
              '[\\321-\\361]|',             // all accented N, n
              '[\\307-\\347]'               // all accented C, c
             ]
             .join(''), modifiers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In some regex implementations a simple `\w` will cover all those.  See http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow letter (with diacritics or not) and some punctuation you can use:

```
^[\w_-]+$
```

where \w stands for any letter and _- are the 2 allowed extra punctuations allowed. Dont-t forget to put the - at the end is used.

Answer (score 0):

For user input in order form I'm using this: [^\w\s+\/_,.@-]
This allows characters for emails, zip-codes, first name, last name etc.