# Regex diacritics in C# not filtering on IsMatch

Tags: c#, regex

I want to return a bool to check that a string contains letters, numbers as well as spaces and dashes. The letters can be from foreign alphabets and need to accept letters such as `é`, `à`, `î`, or `ô`. This is the line of code I have:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(this.UserFirstName, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9À-ž_ -]") == false)
{ return false; }
```

However, it returns `true` even if I have a `#@!` in the string; here on the image I switched the `^` to see if it makes a difference but it doesn't.

[image]

What do I need to change to get the expected result: if there are characters such as `#`, `@`, or `!` in the string then return `false`.

Comment: This may give some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131632/allow-only-letters-and-special-letters-%C3%A9%C3%A8%C3%A0-etc-through-a-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with your regex is that it only checks the first character because of `^` anchor (start of string) and no quantifiers with the character class you defined (i.e. only 1 occurrence is tested). Thus, `Sylvain#@!` will pass as it starts with an allowed character.

You need to use `\p{L}` shorthand class for all Unicode letters with both `^` and `$` anchors and a `+` quantifier:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(this.UserFirstName, @"^[\p{L}\p{N}\p{Zs}_-]+$") == false)
{
  return false; 
}
```

See [regexstorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bN%7d%5cp%7bZs%7d_-%5d%2b%24&i=Maria%24%40%0d%0a%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80&o=m)

In the regex, I also replaced `0-9` with shorthand class `\p{N}` (Unicode class for numeric characters), and  with `\p{Zs}` (Unicode spaces). See more details at [MSDN Supported Unicode General Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories). If you plan to only allow "regular" digits and only a regular space, then just keep your `0-9` range and  in the regex:

```
@"^[\p{L}0-9 _-]+$"
```

Comment: Glad to help. Also, please note that if you plan to accept combining marks, you also need to add `\p{M}` to the character class: `@"^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Zs}_-]+$"`

Comment: Please refer to [Characters, Code Points, and Graphemes or How Unicode Makes a Mess of Things](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html): *In Unicode, `à` can be encoded as two code points: U+0061 (a) followed by U+0300 (grave accent)... The Unicode code point U+0300 (grave accent) is a combining mark.*